# Show all discrete x-axis values on bar graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have spend hours attempting do to something as simple as generating a bar graph where all discrete x-axis labels appear, instead of the values being shown as intervals.

```
ggplot(data=NORM_VET_Ent_2, aes(x=aar,fill=analytt))+geom_bar()
```

The x values are all years from 2000-2020, however, only intervals of 5 years are displayed on the graph
[image]

Don't mind that the axis-labels will be overlapping. I will fix that by rotating the labels

Comment: try `x = factor(aar)` rather than x = aar`

Comment: Thaaanks Allan. That worked like a charm. But there has to be a way to do it without being as intrusive as changing data type?

Comment: You're not changing the data type in your actual data set, only the version you send to ggplot. You want ggplot to draw the years as discrete values, so you need some way of showing this is what you intend. Since it has to be represented internally in ggplot as discrete data in order for axes, limits and transformations to work properly, the simplest thing to do is to pass discrete data. I don't think that's intrusive at all.

Comment: I would consider it intrusive if {ggplot} **didn't** respect the source datatype when plotting my axes. Of course this is subjective :). Also you're making a bar plot. These are discrete visuals, well served by discrete source data.

Comment: Okay, I totally buy your arguments. Thanks a lot guys.